# UITableviewCell recursiveDescription showing no subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

I'm creating a prototype cell using xib and registering the xib after loading my `UITableView`. The cell has been placed with 2 `UILabels` as:[image]

I printed the cell recursiveDescription in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` by keeping a breakpoint.

```
(lldb) po cell.recursiveDescription 
    <HappeningNowSessionsTableViewCell: 0x7fd93bc51300; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 380 65); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fd93bc952d0>>    
    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x7fd93bcf6460; frame = (0 0; 380 65); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fd93bc4b350>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fd93bca0030>>    
    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7fd93bcb6b60; frame = (15 64; 365 1); layer = <CALayer: 0x7fd93bca4410>>
```

I wondered to see no subviews in `UITableViewCellContentView`. I'm able to visualize the assigned data properly in UI.

I do need the subviews of my cell's contentview as per my project requiremnt.

Why is this occuring so?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [UITableViewCells programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7). Particularly the part **Programmatically Adding Subviews to a Cell’s Content View**.

It states that subviews for a UITableViewCell are added to the `-contentView` property and not to `-subviews`